# in CMS October how I can save System log file For all emails

Tags: laravel, backend, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I would like to send an email in addition to any email that will be kept logged in the system I would be happy to help

```
Mail::send('acme.blog::mail.welcome', $vars, function($message) {

    $message->from('us@example.com', 'October');
    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');

});
```

after that I want to keep a log file in the system

Comment: what does this mean "I would like to send an email in addition to any email that will be kept logged in the system" , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask plus there is no research effort from your side

Comment: look about my edit

Comment: may be checkout this plugin =>  https://octobercms.com/plugin/suresoftware-maillog

Comment: Thank you very much I will try. - is there another option besides that?

Answer (score 0):

you can save the parameters the email to the json format and put the data to log.

```
Mail::send('acme.blog::mail.welcome', $vars, function($message) {

    $message->from('us@example.com', 'October');
    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');

});
$vars['template'] = 'acme.blog::mail.welcome';
$vars['email_to'] = 'foo@example.com';
$vars['email_from'] = 'us@example.com';
$vars = json_encode($vars, true);
\Log::info($vars);
```